# What does Victor whisper to Yakov before entering the airplane?

Tags: yuri-on-ice

On episode 2 of *Yuri on Ice*, before Victor goes on the plane, he whispers something in Yakov's ear. I tried googling it but I can't spell it.

What does Victor whisper?

Answer (score 3):

He says "do svidaniya" which is Russian for goodbye.